# Short custom plugin to send email to users

Tags: plugin-development, loop, user-meta, timestamp, plugin-json-api

I have created a very short plugin that is working with a cron job running the below function once every 3 months.

I will explain the steps inside the function:

1. Fetching Producers(a list of users with the role 'producer', 'producer_contributor', and 'administrator')
2. Run a loop for each Producer
3. Grab Producer's most recent broadcast's timestamp via API
4. Compare the most recent broadcast's timestamp of the producer if it is more than 90 days from today.
5. If yes, send email to that Producer.

```
function producer_reminder_email() {

    $argsGet = [
    'method'      => 'GET',
    'headers'     => [
        'X-API-Key' => 'Bearer {{32-CHARACTER ALPHANUMERIC KEY}}',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
];
   
   $producers = get_users( array(
    'role__in' => array( 'producer', 'producer_contributor', 'administrator' ) // get only specific roles
) );

    // No user found.
    if ( empty( $producers ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ( ! empty( $producers ) ) { 
    
    foreach ( $producers as $producer ) {
        
    $expire = strtotime('-90 days'); // Get the Unix timestamp representing 90 days ago
    $producer_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $producer->ID );
    $producerId = get_the_author_meta( 'producer_id', $producer->ID ); //not all producers have data set in this meta field. 
    
    if ( empty( $producer_id ) ) {
        continue; // Skip this iteration and move to the next user
    }
    
    $requestGet = wp_remote_request( 'https://endpoint/api/' .  $producerId  . '/broadcasts' , $argsGet  ) ;
    if( is_wp_error( $requestGet ) ) {
    return false; // Bail early
    }

    $body_responseGet = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $requestGet ), true );
    $timestamp = $body_responseGet[0][timestampEnd]; // get the Unix timestamp of the most recent broadcast, example 1690711552
    
    if ( $timestamp < $expire ) {
    $message = ....
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');  //change the type of email from plain text to html
    wp_mail( $producer_email , 'Reminder Email', $message , $headers );
    
               }
            }
          
        }
}   
add_action( 'producer_reminder_email', 'producer_reminder_email' );
```

The functions seems **not to working correct** and i can't figure out where may be the problem.
I am sure that *get_users* and *wp_remote_request* are working as intended, fetching the users and the timestamp correct.

The problem must be somewhere in the logic because it sends emails to almost all producers (even those without data in *producer_id* field. )

Below the code for simple creating the *producer_id* meta field in users */wp-admin/user-edit.php* :

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
if ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'producer', 'producer_contributor', 'administrator' ) ) ) { ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="playlist">Producer's ID</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="producer_id" id="producer_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'producer_id', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">Set manually producer's ID.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php } }


add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'producer_id', $_POST['producer_id'] );
}
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated.